# rails letter opener is opening mail in unusual way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I am using 2 gems 
1) delayed_job_active_record 
2) letter_opener
I am trying to send a mail to a particular user after 5 minutes.So the mail is sending but the response which I am getting is in 'rich.html.erb' which is opening automatically with my sublime text.And I need a way so that it  should be opened with my browser.So what to do? 
[delayed_job.rb]

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

[User.rb]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   after_save :user_email

   def user_email
        Usermailer.delay.user_mail('raghavvishnoi10@gmail.com')
   end      
end
```

[usermailer.rb]

```
class Usermailer < ActionMailer::Base

    default from: "from@example.com"


    def user_mail(email)
        mail(to: email,subject: "hello")
    end
end
```

And basically this file is opening automatically in my sublime text.I  want this file to be open with my browser 
[rich.html]

```
      <title>hello</title>


    <style type="text/css">
      #container {
        margin: 10px auto;
      }
      #message_headers {
        background: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      #message_headers dl {
        float: left;
        line-height: 1.3em;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #message_headers dt {
        width: 92px;
        margin: 0;
        float: left;
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #7f7f7f;
      }

      #message_headers dd {
        margin: 0 0 0 102px;
      }

      #message_headers p.alternate {
        float: right;
        margin: 0;
      }

      #message_headers p.alternate a {
        color: #09c;
      }

      pre#message_body {
        padding: 4px;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
      }

      iframe {
        border: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="message_headers">
        <dl>
          <dt>From:</dt>
          <dd>from@example.com</dd>






            <dt>Subject:</dt>
            <dd><strong>hello</strong></dd>


          <dt>Date:</dt>
          <dd>Nov 30, 2015 05:33:46 PM IST</dd>


            <dt>To:</dt>
            <dd>raghavvishnoi10@gmail.com</dd>







        </dl>


      </div>


        <iframe seamless="seamless" srcdoc="<base target='_top'>hello"></iframe>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the .erb extension, so that the file ends with .html. Then you can open it in your browser by dragging it into a browser window.

Comment: Oh sorry the file extension is this only rich.html .But it is still opening automatically with sublime text

Comment: Just drag it into your browser, or right-click and chose open with... and chose your browser.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due the .html generated by letter_opener file is opened with the code editor instead of the browser, you can change the default configuration in your system to use the browser when a .html file is open